# Setting text size inside of a Button

Tags: java, javafx

I figured I could create a label, use setFont(new Font(...)), then create a button and use .getText() inside of the Button but it still looks like default fonts etc.

How would I correctly set the font of text inside of a Button?

```
Label startLabel = new Label("Start");
startLabel.setFont(new Font(26));
start = new Button(startL.getText());
```

I figured that would work, but it stayed the same as before.

Comment: Can you post some code? It's really unclear what you mean. What's the relationship between the label and the button?

Comment: There's not really any code to post. Okay, so you know how you can create a Label then use .setFont(double size) to edit the size of the text. Well I was wondering if it would be possible to do that with the text inside of a Button.

Comment: Well of course it is.

Comment: But how? I guess I should've said that instead of saying is it possible.

Comment: Exactly the same way. If you have tried it, post your attempted code and explain what goes wrong. If you haven't tried it, why are you posting here?

Comment: Added code. /4chars

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
start = new Button("Start");
start.setFont(new Font(26));
```

You don't need to create a `Label` unless you actually need a `Label` in your UI.

Answer (score 1):

> 1)You can modify it with `css`,for example:

```
Button button = new Button("Some text");
button.setStyle("-fx-font-size:26px;"); //or (em) or..
```

> 2)You can add the `Label` as a graphic to the `Button`(not
>   recommended)(**a good idea for that would be for example to add a
>   ProgressIndicator inside a Button to show some progress when the
>   Button is pressed**)

```
 Label startLabel = new Label("Start");
  startLabel.setFont(new Font(26));
  Button start = new Button(""); //do not add Text to the Button
  start.setGraphic(startLabel);
```

> 3)Use `setFont(...);` method of `Button`.

```
 Button button = new Button("Some text");
 button.setFont(new Font(26));//you can play more with it creating custom fonts
```